# EntLib Validation Rules Order of Operations?

Tags: enterprise-library, rules, operator-precedence

What determines the order of execution of an EntLib validation rule:

Given the following:

```
<ValidatorComposition(CompositionType.And, Ruleset:="Default")> _
<NotNullValidator(MessageTemplate:="Transaction ID is required.", Ruleset:="Default")> _
<TypeConversionValidator(GetType(Int64), MessageTemplate:="Transaction ID must be numeric.", Ruleset:="Default")> _
<RangeValidator("0", RangeBoundaryType.Exclusive, "0", RangeBoundaryType.Ignore, MessageTemplate:="Transaction ID may not be 0.", Ruleset:="Default")> _
<StringLengthValidator(1, RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive, 19, RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive, MessageTemplate:="Transaction ID must be between 1 and 19 characters in length.", Ruleset:="Default")> _
```

When TransactionID is missing from an object instantiation, the following appended error string would be expected:

```
Transaction ID must be numeric.Transaction ID must be between 1 and 19 characters in length.Transaction ID may not be 0.Transaction ID is required.
```

However, it would seem that the actual order of each error can differ from time to time.  The same errors appear, but in a different order.

I found this out through unit testing, where I knew the data had not changed, and the once passing tests were now failing.

Has anyone ran into this, and have an explanation?

Thanks.